# Xcode 11.6 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to Archive my build in `Xcode 11.6` running on `macOS 10.15.5` and every time I get the same error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code".
In Signing & Capabilities option I've chosen Distribution provisioning profile on both tabs Debug and Release and I've disabled automatic signing.

[image: Picture1]

I have 2 certificates: one for development and one for distribution.

[image: Picture2]

Here is the error:

[image: Picture3]

I've already tried Keychain lock and unlock. On Xcode 10 and macOS 10.14 this worked without any problems.

Can you help me please,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it seems there is a build script that tries to run another script called `copy-www-build-step.sh`, and gets a "Permission Denied" error. The most likely cause is simply that the script file does not have execute permissions (no files have this permission by default, and permissions are often lost when e.g. unzipping an archive).

This can be easily solved by running the following command in Terminal to enable execute permissions:

```sh
chmod +x /path/to/copy-www-build-step.sh
```